# What does the express-validator escape() function?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

What exactly does the express-validator escape() sanitizer? Can't understand. For example:

```
check('name')
  .trim()
  .escape()
  .notEmpty()
  .withMessage('User name can not be empty!')
  .bail()
  .isLength({ min: 3 })
  .withMessage('Minimum 3 characters required!')
  .bail(),
```

Why there is a need to escape() after trim()?

Comment: https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#sanitizers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to robertklep. Every sanitizer is described here:

[Sanitizers](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#sanitizers)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, it replace <, >, &, ', " and / with HTML entities.

You may refer here: [validatorjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)